# UWP ScrollBar not visible in my usercontrol

Tags: xaml, uwp, scintilla

```
<UserControl
x:Class="scintillauwp.ScintillaControlEx"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:scintillauwp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:canvas="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400" SizeChanged="UserControl_SizeChanged" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100">
<Grid x:Name="rootLayout">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <canvas:CanvasControl x:Name="canvas"  Grid.RowSpan="2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                PointerWheelChanged="canvas_PointerWheelChanged" PointerMoved="canvas_PointerMoved" PointerPressed="canvas_PointerPressed" PointerReleased="canvas_PointerReleased" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" PointerEntered="canvas_PointerEntered" KeyUp="canvas_KeyUp" KeyDown="canvas_KeyDown" GotFocus="canvas_GotFocus" LostFocus="canvas_LostFocus" PointerExited="canvas_PointerExited" Draw="canvas_Draw_1"  >
    </canvas:CanvasControl>
    <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1"
             IsTabStop="False"
             Orientation="Vertical"
             HorizontalAlignment="Right" Maximum="10000"  Value="1000" ViewportSize="800" />
    <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar"  IsTabStop="False"
             Orientation="Horizontal"
             Grid.Row="1" />
    <Border  x:Name="ScrollBarSeparator" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}"/>
</Grid>
```

`//Maximum="10000"  Value="1000" ViewportSize="800"------`     is test

Hello everyone，my English is not OK. I'm using google translation.

I'm  transplanting  scintill to UWP. The ScrollBar is not shown in the above code. I tried using ScrollViewer+CanvasVirtualControl，but it needs to modify scintill's code in EditView .
Thanks.
[There are Thumb in the layout of the following figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOBbw.png)

Comment: Two things, remove `Grid.RowSpan="2"` from your canvas, and if your `Border` has any height than it will display over the top of your `ScrollViewer` and hide it as well due to the DOM order, so you might want to remove it also since you you can set the `ScrollViewers` background color directly.

Comment: Thanks,I'm change Grid.RowSpan="2" into something Grid.Row="0", and ScrollBar add a background color .but it still does not show

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I completely missed that you are only using `ScrollBar`, you need to put your Canvas INSIDE of a `ScrollViewer`, a `ScrollBar` by itself will not do anything without a `ScrollPresenter` So you don't even need `Grid` just do this (pseudo example) `<ScrollViewer><canvas:CanvasControl/></ScrollViewer>` and you're done! :)